Geometry Nodes - Crashing with too much geometry
I'm doing some work with artists that hand off hair geometry to me in the form of large (~1 GB) .objs consisting of only vertices and edges. My task is to take these and render them out in a nice way.
I use the following geometry node network on some empty tasked to apply operations to a collection of my choosing:

Basically, the .obj gets hit with some amount of subdivision (right now it's set to 2) and I sweep a circle (a pentagon just to keep things efficient) down each strand.
I have an accompanying python script that imports the obj, transfers it to the collection, then renders the scene so I can just send a bunch of render jobs to a cluster through the CLI.
This render pipeline gives agreeable results, but recently, artists are sending larger .objs (~2 GB) that cause the render jobs to fail; Blender crashes at the step of trying to apply this geometry network to the mesh.
Outside of turning down the amount of subdivisions and the circle resolution, is there anything I can do to prevent crashing, and how well will they scale with larger and larger meshes? I'm fine with having to wait longer to render.

Could you confirm that the crash reason is "out of memory" ?

And does this crash actually result in a crash? As in blender freezes up, writes a crashlog and then suddenly stops running? Or does it just hang forever until you use the Task Manager to kill the process? The latter isn't necessarily a crash it's just memory issues or your CPU struggling with the calculations.

Here's the exact output; it appears to be a Malloc error somewhere:
Malloc returns null: len=18446744066566272672 in Cycles Aligned Alloc, total 82757589672 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'   what():  std::bad_alloc

The memory request to the Malloc function is around 16 Exbibytes. So you are clearly running out of memory. It is about 100 times more than actual supercomputers...

It's strange that it suddenly balloons to exabyte levels of memory; I wouldn't think subdivision twice (x100 as an upper bound) and sweeping a pentagon (x100-ish?) would induce a factor of 10^9.
I suppose this issue is more a matter of ensuring that I don't feed in this .obj such that malloc gets a request that large, then? Would, say, splitting the obj into two discontinuous parts and then separately applying the geometry nodes to both circumvent a malloc that large from getting called?

@StefLAncien I notice that 18446744066566272672 is 264 - 7143278944 so it seems likely that malloc is being given a negative number for some reason, rather than a huge one.
